# What is achieved by .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am learning spring-boot now. May I know what has been achieved by
`.antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()`.
Additionally, I want to know the meaning of ** or /**. Does it enable us to upload JSON content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That specific configuration reads as follows:
All users are able to use HTTP method OPTIONS on all endpoints.

** matches zero or more directories in a path, which basically in your configuration reads as "all endpoints".

For additional details check the following documentation:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/web/server/ServerHttpSecurity.AuthorizeExchangeSpec.Access.html

Answer (score 0):

The intended purpose is to allow OPTIONS requests for correct handling of CORS. Browser do not send `Authorization` headers for CORS preflight requests.